# AngularJS ng-view not loading with partial templates

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

[Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mca6u.jpg)I am working with AngularJS route (*ngRoute*). My `ng-view` does not load the partial template. Here is my code :

[MyHome.html (Start Page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5JWh.jpg)
[enter image description here][Solution Structure]

```
 <html ng-app="Demo">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/SPAScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#!/home">Home </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#!/about">About </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Your Data goes here
                <ng-view> </ng-view>
                <!--<div ng-view="">

                </div>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My Script file :

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-route.min.js" />



var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider

    .when("/home", {templateUrl: "Templates/HomePage.html",controller:"homecontroller"})
    .when("/about", {templateUrl: "Templates/AboutPage.html",controller: "aboutcontroller"})

});

app.controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Home Page";
});

app.controller("aboutcontroller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "About Page";
});
```

AboutPage.html:

```
<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/SPAScript.js"></script>
<h1>
    Welcome To {{message}}
</h1>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Click Me" />
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Enter Some Text"/>
</div>
```

I have included all the code but looks like I am missing out something . Need help from someone. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try removing the `#!` on `<a href="#!/home">Home </a>` and `<a href="#!/about">About </a>`

Comment: I also tried modifying as below:
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head> <title></title><meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/SPAScript.js"></script>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <a href="home">Home </a>
        <a href="about">About </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Your Data goes here
            <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <hr />
</body>
</html>

Comment: And ... is there any error on dev tools console?

Comment: Get an error:
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$compile/tpload?p0=Templates%2FHomePage.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found

Comment: That's probably because the routing system doesn't find the template for the route you're trying to navigate to. Could you post the project structure?

Comment: Solution Structure added in the first line as hyperlink for your reference. I agree with you and I guess that's the problem too... Thanks!

Comment: OK, great! If you get stuck again, just ask :)

Comment: Problem still exists any issue with the solution structure that you see ?

Comment: In your routing system, for the parameter `templateUrl` try instead `templateUrl: "../Templates/HomePage.html".That really depends on how the file structure is being managed in your project

Comment: No luck. Still receive the same error :
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$compile/tpload?p0=..%2FTemplates%2FAboutPage.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found

Comment: How would you access directly to **AboutPage.html raw html** through the web browser? That could give you a clue. Try that path instead. This is very difficult since this is solved by a _try and failure_ proccess